# Mono HttpListener HTTP/2 support

Tags: networking, mono, http2

How can I use HTTP/2 with HttpListener in Mono?

I've switched on SSL, but still HTTP/1.1 is used for communication.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in http://www.mono-project.com/news/2017/08/04/upgrading-httpwebrequest/

In the future versions of mono, protocol support will depend on the platform.

From the post:

```
Windows/.NET Framework                        HttpWebRequest
Windows/Mono                                  HttpWebRequest
Windows/UWP Windows native                    WinHttpHandler (HTTP 2.0 capable)
Windows/.NET Core   Windows native            WinHttpHandler (HTTP 2.0 capable)
Android/Xamarin Default to Android’s HTTP transport
Can be configured to be HttpWebRequest.
iOS, tvOS, watchOS/Xamarin  Default to        NSUrlSession (HTTP 2.0 capable)
Can be configured to use HttpWebRequest.
macOS/Xamarin   Default to                    NSUrlSession (HTTP 2.0 capable)
Can be configured to use                      HttpWebRequest
macOS/Mono  HttpWebRequest
macOS/.NET Core                               libcurl-based HTTP transport (HTTP 2.0 capable)
Linux/Mono  HttpWebRequest
Linux/.NET Core                               libcurl-based HTTP transport (HTTP 2.0 capable)
```

Comment: Please quote the relevant parts from the linked page into your post.